# Pasting a variable with quotation marks inside of regex in r

Tags: regex, r

The core of my question is using "paste" to put a variable inside of a regex with escape characters for quotation marks.   This is the answer on other stackoverflow questions -- but it just doesn't seem to be working.  What I think makes this question unique from those is that it's combining both elements -- using paste to put a variable in regex, and using escape characters for quotation marks.  I've also tried using "cat", another frequent answer, with no luck.

What I'm trying to do is to make it easier to filter by name through a list of thousands of names.  (I'm moving from visualization software (Spotfire) to R and I miss the listbox filters.)  I would be very happy with any advice on how to perform this task.

And, yes, I'm new to R programming (and programming in general.)  Stackoverflow has been the overwhelmingly best resource.  Y'all must be a bunch of geniuses out there,

Thank you--

```
# mtcars example for filtering and finding names for the stack overflow question

data(mtcars)

# make the data match my dataframe, where I don't have row names but have a column with the name
mtcars$carname  <- NA  #declare the variable
mtcars$carname  <- rownames(mtcars) #assign the names to a column

findcar  <- function() {

  while(TRUE) {
    print("Type the car's name:")     
    apxname  <- readline() #approx name
    #type in Merc for this example
    carlst  <- mtcars$carname[(grepl("(apxname)",mtcars$carname, ignore.case = TRUE))] #list of cars that matches the approximate name
          # if I type   . . . (grepl("(Merc)", mtcars$carname, . . . )) it works great
    #So per other stackoverflow responses, I've tried using "paste" or "paste0" without success
    #I can't get this to work
    #carlst  <- mtcars$carname[(grepl(paste0('\"(',apxname, ')\"', sep=""),mtcars$carname, ignore.case = TRUE))]
    print("Here's the list of similar customers:")
    print(carlst)
    print("Type the number of your car:")
    carnum  <- readline()  #car number
    therightone  <- carlst[as.numeric(carnum)] 
    paste("You selected",therightone,"Is this the car (Y/N)?", sep=" ")
    carconf  <- readline()  #car confirmation
    if(carconf == "Y") break)
  }
return(therightone)
}
```

Comment: Please expand on "but it just doesn't seem to be working". Thanks.

Comment: Use `carlst <- mtcars$carname[(grepl(get("apxname"), x = mtcars$carname, ignore.case = TRUE))]`.

Comment: I cannot edit this, because it is merely one character, but you also have to delete the parenthesis after the `break` statement.

Comment: You don't need or want quotes there; you need to evaluate that variable. You don't need the parentheses for `grepl` either; it'll match everything regardless. You _may_ need to `paste` a `$` after it to indicate the end of the line, so you can differentiate between things like `Mazda RX4` and `Mazda RX4 Wag`. Generally, you need something like `grepl(paste0('Mazda RX4', '$'), rownames(mtcars))`

Comment: @alistaire The OP seems to want the user to select a car brand first (based on fuzzy matching) and then offer him all possible choices to choose the exact match from a list of options. So there will not be the need to differentiate between different models.

Comment: @matthias Then all he needs is `grepl(apxname, rownames(mtcars))`

Comment: @alistaire Indeed. I didn't realize this at first. However, there is still the aforementioned typo in the OPs code that needs to be fixed. I will delete my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this is an unbelievably fast response.

I have success with get("apxname") (not get(apxname), no quotes, so I learned something there) and, simply with apxname.

So it looks like my regex was too complicated and I didn't need the parenthesis () and quotes "".

I'm too new to be clear as to why I ever needed them in the first place. I built my first regex at https://regex101.com/ and developed a fairly
complex regex, and then just stuck with the pattern.
I think my problem is solved.  I'm going to run with the straightforward grepl you've shown me that works.  
Thanks!

Comment: (. . .and the extra parenthesis after break, nice catch.)  Where/how do I check off "answered"?

Comment: If @alistaire doesn't want to write up an answer, you can write one up yourself, as long as it will be useful to future visitors.Otherwise you can just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the particular issue, reference `apxname` as a variable, not a string. Cleaned up a little more, including the typo mentioned by Mathias above and wrapping the car confirmation prompt in `print`:

```
findcar  <- function() {

    while(TRUE) {
        print("Type the car's name:")     
        apxname  <- readline() # approx name
        # list of cars that matches the approximate name
        carlst  <- rownames(mtcars)[grepl(apxname, rownames(mtcars), ignore.case = TRUE)]
        print("Here's the list of similar customers:")
        print(carlst)
        print("Type the number of your car:")
        carnum  <- readline()  # car number
        therightone  <- carlst[as.numeric(carnum)] 
        print(paste("You selected",therightone,"Is this the car (Y/N)?", sep=" "))
        carconf  <- readline()  # car confirmation
        if(carconf == "Y") break
    }
    return(therightone)
}
```

This version returns car names; if you want to return all stats for the car, you need something like

```
findcar  <- function() {

    while(TRUE) {
        print("Type the car's name:")     
        apxname  <- readline() # approx name
        # list of cars that matches the approximate name
        carlst  <- mtcars[grepl(apxname, rownames(mtcars), ignore.case = TRUE),]
        print("Here's the list of similar customers:")
        print(carlst)
        print("Type the number of your car:")
        carnum  <- readline()  # car number
        therightone  <- carlst[as.numeric(carnum),] 
        print(paste("You selected",rownames(therightone),"Is this the car (Y/N)?", sep=" "))
        carconf  <- readline()  # car confirmation
        if(carconf == "Y") break
    }
    return(therightone)
}
```

The "select a number" prompt could use work, as no row numbers are printed, but it works, at least.